# Bootstrap - pull-right element overlaps text content

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, angular-ui-bootstrap

Using **AdminLTE template** for creating dashboard layout with **ANGULAR 5 + bootstrap 3.4**,
In one of the components I have to align image, title and a dropdown in a row which when resized causes the dropdown to overlap the text content of title.

full-page view :

[image]

resized or minimized browser:

[image]

HTML snippet:

```
<div  class="col-md-4"> //---> entire layout split between 3 boxes 
      <span  class="info-box-icon-sm"> //---> adds float:left property for the icon
        <i  class="fa fa-search" id="escalatedIcon"></i>
      </span>
      <h4 >Search Requests</h4>
      <div class="box-select pull-right">
        <select class="ng-untouched">
           <option class="select-bg-white" value="country">
            country
          </option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I've tried adding individual div's to each element & then add boostrap "col" sizing but the drop down always seems to be overlapping the title, could I be simple as missing something since I'm a beginner to responsive designing?
Appreciate your response

Comment: use class `text-right` ...

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/online_bootstrap_editor.php try your code here, it seems ok

Comment: @AbdullahAlNoor tried 'text-right' since bootstrap 3 doesn't support float-right yet no solution

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve? How should the layout be?
The problem is in css of your h4, it's not formatted. h4 is inline, so it will treated like common text.

```
<div  class="col-md-4"> //---> entire layout split between 3 boxes 
      <span  class="info-box-icon-sm"> //---> adds float:left property for the icon
        <i  class="fa fa-search" id="escalatedIcon"></i>
      </span>
      <div style="white-space: normal;"> <-- give  css
      <h4 >Search Requests</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="box-select pull-right">
        <select class="ng-untouched">
           <option class="select-bg-white" value="country">
            country
          </option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
```

is it set to nowrap? and check the overflow of the text. Better to wrap h4 in a div so you can set the overflow and wrap text

```
normal  Sequences of whitespace will collapse into a single whitespace. Text will wrap when necessary. This is default  
nowrap  Sequences of whitespace will collapse into a single whitespace. Text will never wrap to the next line. The text continues on the same line until a <br> tag is encountered  
pre Whitespace is preserved by the browser. Text will only wrap on line breaks. Acts like the <pre> tag in HTML 
pre-line    Sequences of whitespace will collapse into a single whitespace. Text will wrap when necessary, and on line breaks   
pre-wrap    Whitespace is preserved by the browser. Text will wrap when necessary, and on line breaks   
initial Sets this property to its default value. Read about initial 
inherit Inherits this property from its parent element. Read about inherit
```

Comment: missed out the wrapping div in the post, so i had already tried overflow:'hidden' and now tried white-space property as well but it overlaps still

Comment: have you added to use display: block?

Comment: Can you please add your css for that section?

Comment: DIV wrapping around  { display: block;
    white-space: normal;
    overflow: hidden;
}

Comment: I can't see the culprit of your css. better to inspect the element and see which css is used right now. sometimes the css from one section ruined other section

Comment: i was thinking float property of dropdown might be the culprit, is there any way to anchor down the text when resizing other than display properties

Comment: I'm sorry, I really can't find the problem with your current code. It may linger around other area as I tried my suggestion and they don't overlap

Comment: please use jsfiddle so I can check the problem

Comment: yeah..online editors doesnt work with adminlte layout as of now, hence unable to post a fiddle